# How to position custom tab bar buttons percentage wise across the x axis?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, autolayout

I have a custom tab bar with my own images as buttons. The problem is adapting this for auto layout - I know to stick the leftmost and rightmost buttons to their respective sides but for the middle buttons I need them to be x * #of-button/total-buttons-minus-1.

So, for instance, if I have 4 total buttons across my tab bar, I need the second button to be 1/3 (minus half of its width, which is a separate issue) ways along the tab bar starting from the left side and the second button to be 2/3 of the way across the tab bar.

How can I program this without code using auto layout?

Below is an attached image that shows what I'm dealing with.

[image: custom tab bar with auto layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make several simple steps:

1. Place transparent views between each two buttons
2. For each transparent view left and right spacing to buttons set to 0

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqhrJ.png

3. Set each view to have same width. Select all transparent views by holding command and clicking on each view and then select "Equal Widths"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/olMwH.png

Comment: This seems it should definitely work but is this the only way to do it?

Comment: If you want to do it without adding any code - this is the only way as i know.